# How to pass values between two event handlers?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax7, dynamics-365-operations

In my first event handler, I will collect all the fields I need from the **SalesTable** form. In this form, I need to get these fields from the **SalesLine**. Below is my code:

```
[FormEventHandler(formStr(SalesTable), FormEventType::PostRun)]
public static void SalesTable_OnPostRun(xFormRun sender, FormEventArgs e)
{
      SalesLine   salesLine;
      SalesTable  salesTable = sender.dataSource(formDataSourceStr(SalesTable,salesTable)).cursor();

      select ItemId, SalesId, ShippingDateConfirmed from salesLine
         where salesLine.SalesId == SalesTable.SalesId;
}
```

After that, this next event handler is the **OnClick** event of a button found in another form..

```
[FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(SalesAvailableDlvDates, TransferToConfirmedButton), FormControlEventType::Clicked)]
public static void TransferToConfirmedButton_OnClicked(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)
{
    //some code here
}
```

In this event handler of a different form which is **SalesAvailableDlvDates**, here I need the fields from my ***SalesLine table*** which I obtained from the **SalesTable** form.  Because in here, this is the button needed to be triggered where this will place values into a newly created table.

Is there anyway I can pass the values from the **SalesTable event handler** to the **SalesAvailableDlvDates event handler**?

Because in SalesAvailableDlvDates, I COULD NOT obtain the SalesLine data. Is it possible to pass values from one event handler to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SalesAvailableDlvDates` form event handler you can obtain the form caller. Then if `salesCalcAvailableDlvDates` is a `SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesTable` or `SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesLine` you can get data you needed from the corresponding `parm` method.

```
[FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(SalesAvailableDlvDates, TransferToConfirmedButton), FormControlEventType::Clicked)]
public static void TransferToConfirmedButton_OnClicked(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)
{
    SalesTable                              salesTable;
    SalesLine                               salesLine;
    SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates              salesCalcAvailableDlvDates;
    SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesLine    salesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesLine;
    SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesTable   salesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesTable;
    FormRun                                 formRun;
    ;

    formRun = sender.formRun() as FormRun;
    salesCalcAvailableDlvDates = formRun.args().caller();

    switch (classIdGet(salesCalcAvailableDlvDates))
    {
        case classNum(SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesLine):
            salesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesLine = salesCalcAvailableDlvDates as SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesLine;
            salesLine = salesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesLine.parmSalesLine();
            salesTable = salesLine.salesTable();
            break;

        case classNum(SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesTable):
            salesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesTable = salesCalcAvailableDlvDates as salesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesTable;
            salesTable = salesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesTable.parmSalesTable();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir Aliaksandr! Really appreciate everytime you reply! :) regarding your reply sir, why is salesCalcAvailableDlvDates used? and how can I use the SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates_SalesLine syntax?

Comment: Hi sir, SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates is a class, did the salesCalcAvailableDlvDates = sender.args().caller(); but it has an error, it is not valid in this context.

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear enough, please check the updated answer.

Comment: Hi Sir Aliaksandr thank you for this! It worked for my problem. However, is it okay if you could include an explanation? I didn't quite get how it worked and why SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates was used.

Comment: Just look into `init` method of `SalesAvailableDlvDates`form.